# Retry action observable after catch

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have an epic where I'm calling API and this API has authorization and token can expire. I want to try to refresh token and if refreshing was success retry action.

```
action$ => 
    action$.ofType(actionTypes.GET_DATA)
        .mergeMap(action =>
            ajax.getJSON('/api/endpoint', headers)
            .map(response => setData(response))
            .catch(error => Observable.concat(Observable.of({type: actionTypes.REFRESH_TOKEN}, Observable.of({type: actionTypes.GET_DATA}))
        ));
```

I've tried to concat streams but looks like it goes into an infinity loop.

Comment: It sounds like your `REFRESH_TOKEN` action is asynchronous and is handled by an epic. With the actions emitted as they are in the `catch`, the dispatch of `GET_DATA` is going to happen immediately and that's where your loop is.

Comment: @cartant that's right, but how to fix it? Do synchronous request `REFRESH_TOKEN`?

Comment: You have to split it into `REFRESH_TOKEN`, `REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCEEDED`, `REFRESH_TOKEN_FAILED`, etc. - as  you would with a typical epic. You can then do something like `Observable.concat(Observable.of({ type: actionTypes.REFRESH_TOKEN }), action$.ofType(actionTypes.REFRESH_TOKEN_SUCCEEDED).take(1).mapTo({ type: actionTypes.GET_DATA }))`